# returning multiple variables to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, view

So I am new to Laravel.
I know how to pass an array to a view. I am trying to alter that basic concept by passing other variable to the view as well.

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('sites', function()
{
$thosting = DB::table('sites')
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(hosting_fee) as thosting'))
            ->where('active', True)
            ->get();

 $tdomain = DB::table('sites')
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(domain_fee) as tdomain'))
            ->where('active', True)
            ->get();

$atotal = $thosting + $tdomain;

$sites = Site::where('active', True)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get();
return View::make('sites')
    ->with('sites', $sites)
    ->with('thosting', $thosting)
    ->with('tdomain', $tdomain)
    ->with('atotal', $atotal);

//var_dump($sites);
});
```

here is view sites.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="container well">
<table class="table-condensed">
<th>Annual Hosting</th><th>Annual Domain Name</th><th>Total Annual Income</th>
<tr>
    <td>{{ thosting }}</td>
    <td>{{ tdomain }}</td>
    <td>{{ atotal }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<h1>Hosting Accounts - Nearest to expiration </h1>
@foreach($sites as $site)
    <a href="{{ URL::to('edit', $site->id) }}"><p>{{ $site->host_renewal_date }} -           {{$site->site}}</p></a>
@endforeach
@stop

</div>
```

The $site->Id etc displays a list of sites, as expected. but the 3 new variables I passed, thosting, tdomain and atotal, cause an error when I try to display them like {{ thosting }. The error is ErrorException, defined (E_unknown)

```
Use of undefined constant thosting - assumed 'thosting' (View: C:\Users\myname\Desktop\websites\laravel\first\app\views\sites.blade.php)
```

I assume I am not accessing the variables right I tried 
    echo thosting

that did not work either. The docs does not address returning multiple variables or not array variables. Any help from a seasoned vet is appreciated. In the end, all im trying to figure out is how to return to the view data from several DB queries.

thanks

Comment: You don't have to call `with` for each variable. You can just pass an associative array to `View::make` as the second argument.

Comment: Scheisse_minelli my main thing is not knowing how to display the variable in the blade. If an associative array would help, I am interested if you can show me how to do it. thanks

Comment: The first answer is completely accurate. Within `{{ $var }}`, you just need to treat it like a small php statement. It is roughly equivalent to `<?php echo $var; ?>`. In the `with` method, the first argument (string) will be the name of the variable once it gets to the view. If the first answer doesn't work for you, it is highly likely that those variables are undefined upon arrival.

Comment: I just tried <?php echo $thosting ?>. it gives the array to string conversion error. my first argument in my "with" method is called thosting. $thosting both in the route and the view show as not being empty when I print_r or var_dump.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use $ in PHP variables also inside Blade views, otherwise it will try to find a constant. So just change to

```
<td>{{ $thosting }}</td>
<td>{{ $tdomain }}</td>
<td>{{ $atotal }}</td>
```

Comment: as hard as it may seem, im still getting error. this one says ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Array to string conversion (View: C:\Users\Norman Bird\Desktop\websites\laravel\first\app\views\sites.blade.php)....I believe that means object is a string and not an array. I tried iterating through with @foreach, but still more errors.

Comment: this is how i have it in the blade:  <td>{{ $thosting }}</td>
      <td>{{ $tdomain }}</td>

Comment: remember my DB query in my routes.php is using RAW SQL method and returning a COUNT. When I use Print_r, I can see that $thosting in the count AND the blade has the value of '273'. Just getting errors when I try and display it in the blade. I have tried $thosting, thosting, thosting->thosting, thosting[0], $thosting->...all sorrounded by {{ }}, but no luck. I have tried <?php echo $thosting ?>. I do not know enough to know if it is because I just use routes instead of a controller?? I believe we can just use route.

Comment: Hmmm this may help. This is what Print_r reports when its is run in the blade: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sum(hosting_fee)] => 273.00 ) )

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks everyone. This is what I finally got to work:

{{ $thosting[0]->thosting }}

Print_r gave me the clue that there was a property name for the object, and since i had 'sum(hosting_fee) as thosting'. I tried to point to thosting(the AS name) and it worked. After all it is an array. Great learning experience.

Would be nice if there was a way to add all these learning examples to the Laravel documentation, which only has several examples of what is possible with a lot left out.

thanks all.